# Склонение и согласование слова "драже"

Tags: выбор-слов

Можно ли сказать:

- На столе стоит чаша с драже.
- В чаше драже жёлтого и синего цветов.
- Кирилл взял одно драже из чаши.
- Кирилл дал Тане два драже — синего и жёлтого цветов.

Основной вопрос: корректно ли использовать слово *драже* как для обозначения сорта конфет, так и для обозначения каждой отдельной конфетки?

Answer (score 1):

> **Можно ли** сказать:
>
> • На столе стоит чаша с драже.
>
> •   Кирилл взял одно драже...
>
> •   Кирилл дал Тане два драже...

Ну а почему же нельзя? Ведь именно так практически все и говорят...

Можно ли сказать как-либо по-иному? Тоже можно. Во всяком случае, Нагибин так когда-то сказал:

> *Наконец он жестко прикрикнул на себя: «Довольно!», разжал кулак — на ладони лежала одна-единственная полурастаявшая **дражинка**.*

См. [**"Русскую грамматику"**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/380-432.html):

> § 409. Существительные с суф. ***-инк(а)*** (фонемат. |инк|; перед
>   |к| беглая |a1|) имеют значение "одна маленькая частица однородной
>   массы, названной мотивирующим словом, имеющим собирательное
>   значение"...   Тип продуктивен в разг. и художественной речи; окказ...
>   ***дражинка*** (от *драже*. Нагиб.).

Comment: Слава, вы говорите, что все так и говорят. А где примеры?

Comment: А Вы сами примеры привели, я не стал повторяться. Драже -- оно и есть драже, и неважно, из чего оно сделано. И если можно сказать _одно/два/три драже_ про витаминки, то почему нельзя точно так же говорить про конфетки? В чём разница? В том, что  обычно драже-конфеты едят горстями?

Comment: Да, именно в том. Теоретически, да,возможно. Но в на практике, лучше сказать:  дражинка.

Answer (score 0):

***Драже*** в значении отдельной конфеты не употребляется. Об этом свидетельствует словарное значение. Однако "драже" имеет и другое значение: Лекарство в виде таблеток, покрытых твердой оболочкой и похожих по внешнему виду на конфеты драже; используется в лечебных целях или как витаминизирующее средство.

Вот в этом втором значении драже может с количественным значением, о чем свидетельствует примеры из Интернета и Национального корпуса русского языка.

> Старушка вынула из кармана маленький пузырек. На дне виднелись **два драже.** - Сердечные. [Валерий БУТАЕВ. Михаил Зурабов: Сложные рецепты нужны, чтобы лекарства не ушли налево! // Комсомольская правда, 2005.02.01]
>
> Сухофрукты ― **20 г 1 драже** витаминов «Гексавит» Сахар ― 3 с половиной ложки [Вероника Сивкова. Кто кормит армию? (2001) // «Аргументы и факты», 2001.07.04]
>
> **Два драже** в день или… три раза в день? [Разговор в семейном кругу // Из материалов Саратовского университета, 1960-1980]
>
> Жанин® следует принимать п**о 1 драже/сут** непрерывно в течение 21 дня.
>
> Блистерная упаковка препарата Триквилар **содержит 21 драже,** размещенные по кругу.

Comment: Как тогда сказать одна конфета, *имеющая тип драже*?